# UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler question

Tags: iphone, uiapplication, uilocalnotification

guys :)
I have an iOS alarm app, which uses UILocalNotification-s to schedule the user defined alarms if the app enters background. Since this (in my implementation) can be a relatively long process, I need to make sure that the registering of the notifications is completed before the app goes inactive. I read that there is a method in UIApplication: beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler, which asks iOS for more time, so that it can complete its tasks, but I have no idea how to use it. These (void(^)(void)) parameters scare me :). I know it's too much to ask, but... if I have a method [self registerLocalNotifications], which registeres all local notifications, can you please point me how to make sure the method finishes before the app goes to background. Huge thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like good sample code where you can see the usage of blocks ^{} together with applicationDidEnterBackground: http://iphonesdkdev.blogspot.com/2010/04/local-push-notification-sample-code-os.html